# What are the differences between Expedition to Castle Ravenloft (3.5) and the Castle Ravenloft Board Game?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ravenloft, books

Is this book, **Expedition to Castle Ravenloft D&D 3.5**

[image: Expedition to Castle Ravenloft D&D 3.5]

the same thing as the book in the **Castle Ravenloft Board Game** here

[image: Castle Ravenloft Board Game] ?

The board game includes a rule book and a scenario book.

The two books have different covers, from what I can tell, but I'm just not informed enough to know if they have the same 3.5 content, or aside from the covers, if they are the same thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**, going by the [first amazon review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3HGMNJSS4LQIE/ref=cm_cr_dp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0786955570&nodeID=165793011&tag=&linkCode=) the board game is a 4.0 product, and therefore it cannot be the same as the 3.5 Castle Ravenloft book.

Comment: That's correct, the board game is a board game, with rules derived from 4e. Shares nothing other than overall theme with Expedition to Castle Ravenloft.

Comment: Agreed. The board game is a stand alone board game based loosely on the 4.0 rules. While it might give you some ideas for campaigns, and the figures and map tiles could be used in your game if you wish, it won't provide much more to you than that.

Comment: It's important to add that the Ravenloft covers have often been recycled across editions.